# Cypher - Gantt chart from variable length relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher, relationship, gantt-chart, variable-length

I'm new to Cypher, self taught so far. I've managed to get creative with basic queries but am now hitting something I have no idea how to achieve....

Given a list of job ID dependencies:

```
│"A"│"Rel"        │"B"│
│29 │"DependantOn" │8 │
│21 │"DependantOn" │8 │
│20 │"DependantOn" │8 │
│22 │"DependantOn" │8 │
│24 │"DependantOn" │9 │
│25 │"DependantOn"│9 │
│23 │"DependantOn"│9 │
│26 │"DependantOn"│11│
│20 │"DependantOn"│11│
│22 │"DependantOn"│11│
│31 │"DependantOn"│23│
│8  │"DependantOn"│1│
│11 │"DependantOn"│1│
│29 │"DependantOn"│1│
│20 │"DependantOn"│1│
│20 │"DependantOn"│10│
│30 │"DependantOn"│10│
│30 │"DependantOn"│20│
│16 │"DependantOn"│5│
│16 │"DependantOn"│5│
│17 │"DependantOn"│5│
│12 │"DependantOn"│5│
│9  │"DependantOn"│2│
│28 │"DependantOn"│2│
│13 │"DependantOn"│2│
│27 │"DependantOn"│13│
│28 │"DependantOn"│13│
│29 │"DependantOn"│15│
│30 │"DependantOn"│15│
│25 │"DependantOn"│14│
│31 │"DependantOn"│14│
│9  │"DependantOn"│3│
│25 │"DependantOn"│3│
│23 │"DependantOn"│3│
│27 │"DependantOn"│3│
│23 │"DependantOn"│12│
│31 │"DependantOn"│12│
│25 │"DependantOn"│6│
│14 │"DependantOn"│6│
│31 │"DependantOn"│6│
│29 │"DependantOn"│7│
│30 │"DependantOn"│7│
│15│"DependantOn"│7│
│10│"DependantOn"│4│
│18│"DependantOn"│4│
│19│"DependantOn"│4│
```

I'd like to create a table to show the job's run Level based on the longest path and to show that longest path, like a Gnatt chart:

```
> L1 >>>  L2 >>> L3 >>> L4
> 1  >>>   8 >>>  20
>          8 >>> >>> >>> 29
>          8 >>>  21
>          8 >>>  22
> 2  >>>   9 >>>  23
> 3  >>>   9
>          9 >>>  24
>          9 >>>  25
> 4  >>>  10 >>>  20
>         11 >>>  20
> 1  >>>  11 >>>  26
> 1  >>> >>> >>>  20 >>> 30
> 5  >>>  12 >>> >>> >>> 31
> 2  >>>  13 >>>  27
> 3  >>> >>> >>>  23 >>> 31
>         12 >>>  23
> 6  >>>  14 >>>  25
> 7  >>>  15 >>> >>> >>> 29
>         11 >>>  22
> 1  >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> 29
>         10 >>> >>> >>> 30
> 5  >>>  16
> 5  >>>  17
> 2  >>> >>> >>>  28
>         13 >>>  28
>         15 >>> >>> >>> 30
>         14 >>> >>> >>> 31
> 3  >>> >>> >>>  25
> 3  >>> >>> >>>  27
> 6  >>> >>> >>>  25
> 6  >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> 31
> 7  >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> 29
> 7  >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> 30
> 4  >>>  18
> 4  >>>  19
```

I tried using `(:File)-[:DependantOn*3]->(:File)` and `collect with` the same for `*2, *1, *0` and then sort, but this didn't work. I need some way to identify what's a L1, L2, L3, L4 AND what the longest path is, allocate them to the correct level with the "nulls" becoming ">>>" where applicable.

I can't use [*] or (*) as there are many other nodes and relationships off these nodes (such as file content, data types etc.)

Any pointer would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
MATCH p= (start:File)-[:TRIGGER*0..3]->(end:File)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (()-[:DependantOn]->(start))
RETURN end, MAX(length(p))+1 AS level
```

It would return 29 at L3, where it should be I guess, because it only depends on items at L2

Comment: Thanks @Graphileon, that's helped. It's answered what I was looking for, but in another way.